# wp_tiny_mce function not found

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to add the embedded TinyMCE editor to content area using the code:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'tinyMCE_comment_form' );

function tinyMCE_comment_form() {

    wp_tiny_mce(false, array(
        'mode' => 'exact',
        'elements' => 'comment',
        'height' => 200,
        'plugins' => 'inlinepopups,wpdialogs,wplink,media,wpeditimage,wpgallery,paste,tabfocus',
        'forced_root_block' => false,
        'force_br_newlines' => true,
        'force_p_newlines' => false,
        'convert_newlines_to_brs' => true
    ));

}
```

defined in **functions.php** of my theme. For some reason if I load a page with comments there it returns the error **wp_tiny_mce is not found**. Do you know how to fix it? Maybe I chosen the wrong action?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WP 3.3+ I would recommend giving the new "wp_editor()" function a shot. I've used it in several plugins and even on the front end of sites and it's pretty handy.

More detail on how to use it can be found here http://soderlind.no/archives/2011/09/25/front-end-editor-in-wordpress-3-3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your specific requirements, but I've used this to get a "condensed" version of the TinyMce editor on my comments form:

```
    <?php
        add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'tinyMCE_comment_form' );
    function tinyMCE_comment_form() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo includes_url( 'js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js' ); ?>"></script>;
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinyMCE.init({
                theme : "advanced",
                mode: "specific_textareas",
                language: "",
                skin: "default",
                theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold, italic, underline, blockquote, strikethrough, bullist, numlist, undo, redo, link, unlink',
                theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
                theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
                theme_advanced_buttons4: '',
                elements: 'comment',
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
```

*If you need more specific
functionality not included in the
sample I've provided, post your
specific need and I'll try to help you
out.*

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how could I change the script initialization to let TinyMCE use plugins like wplink, for example?

Comment: Sorry, that's the extent of my tinymce "hacking" ability. I've tried a few things, but none have worked. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an admin function... outside of the admin!

`wp_tiny_mce` is defined in `wp-admin/includes/post.php` - you'll need to include the file manually, or use an alternative as @Jeremy suggests.